# VIM: unmap period key in normal mode

Tags: vim, key, unbind, period

I try to use the `EasyMotion` plugin, but I don't want to use the normal `leader key`, which is the `\`-key in my case. I also don't intend to change the `leader key` all together, as it might break things in `vim-latex`.

So I thought about using the `period`-key for this (I am already using the `comma`-key for going into `command-line` mode), because I never really use its repeat feature:

This is what I have tried so far in my .vimrc:

```
nunmap .
let g:EasyMotion_leader_key = '.'
```

The second command works just fine as it seems. But I can't unbind the period key with the first command (E31: No such mapping). If I am wrong with only wanting to unbind the `period`-key in normal mode, then feel free to correct me.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: I just want to remind, useing `.` as a lead may not a good idea. in normal mode `.` does repeat. `:h .` see detail. you will lose this nice feature if you use `.` as a "leader".

Comment: @Kent I haven't really had any use for it. That's why I thought about using it as a leader in this case. If you have any good example on why it is so helpful, then feel free to comment on it.

Comment: I think it is very useful feature. I used it everyday (without almost).  I know this cannot convince you. There are too many examples with `.` to repeat changes. comment area doesn't support code format very well. So you can try it a little by yourself. also there is a plugin "repeat" to extend the function of `.`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can disable the dot from working in normal mode by using

```
nnoremap . <NOP>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed for unintentional `Q` presses:)

Answer (score 1):

The error says  it all. There is  no such mapping. `nunmap` is  used to remove
user maps, and `.` is a built-in command, not a map, so you don't really unmap
it…

It's a bit unclear,  but if it works as the desired leader,  then you can just
remove the line unmapping `.`. It's not needed.

Comment: Well, it works as far as I can use `period` as the `leader key` for EasyMotion.
The thing is the following:
If I type period once and then the appropriate key in EasyMotion, it works as it should. But if I type the period two times, it behaves like the default way, which is repeating the last command.

It just feels somewhat "poor" to me, to have a key that can act in a way that I clearly don't want to. The `period`-key should only be the leader for EasyMotion and nothing else.

I thought it would be possible, as I can, for instance, remap `comma` to give me a `colon` in normal mode.

Comment: @Goliathus Ah, I understand. Well then FDinoff indeed placed the answer you were looking for. If you can't unmap it, map it to nothing! :-) I just can't imagine myself without the `.` command…